# COUNT returning array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the number of images in each gallery by using the below query in a foreach statement

`$total = $connect->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos WHERE gallery = '$row[id]'");`

To print this out I'm then using `$total[0]` which returns Array - how do I retrieve the number?

Comment: query()-functions usually return a resource, not an array. Without knowing what kind of object $connect is, we can't know.

Comment: Whats `echo '<pre>'.print_r($total,true).'</pre>';` look like?

Comment: Obligatory [SQL Injection Humor Link](http://xkcd.com/327/) (with a serious point).

Comment: @FaceOfJock: Is that like the Face of Boe?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use PDO prepare statements in my db class, that should protect me from 1st order injection right? I'm still getting the hang of MySQL etc. :L

Comment: @JoshMc: In the above, you're not using a prepared statement. You're using string concatenation, which is the classic SQL injection vector. Now, it could well be that `$row[id]` is *already* sanitized. You would know, and of course, if it is, you're totally fine. It's just not obvious from the above. And it's a great comic. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the information, much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$total = $connect->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as nImages FROM photos WHERE gallery = '$row[id]'");
```

then you can read it like this

```
$total[0]["nImages"]
```

Answer (score 1):

if `$connect` is mysqli object:

```
$total = $connect->query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM photos WHERE gallery = '$row[id]'
")->fetch_assoc();

// $total['count']
```

**Notice:** Use `PDO` library and `param binding` to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively use fetchColumn instead of query

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and oddly enough the array key was the COUNT(*) text so I litterally have to reference it to get the value I wanted.

```
[allUsers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [COUNT(*)] => 606
                        )

                )
```

In order to access it I literally had to access the array key.

```
$selectResult[0]['COUNT(*)']; 

Array
(
    [savedInfo] => Array
        (
            [allUsers] => 606
        )

)
```

Only thing to note is, to program this strongly so you dont run into an error, when I am saving the data I look to see if the original response is an array or not. So not sure if this fix is dirty or not.